# Accessing string array from class member function

Tags: c++, class, dynamic-arrays, member-functions

I'm using a basic class and trying to access a member string array in a member function.  I'm confused because the string array initializes and gets freed without any memory errors (Dr. Memory) if I only call the `set_words`, `print_words`, and `del_words` functions:

```
class XWORD {
  public:
    int vdir;
    int len;
    int wid;
    int nWords;
    char ** arr;
    char ** words;     
    ...
};

void XWORD::set_words(int istart, int inWords, char* iwords[]) {
    int w = istart;
    int k = 0;
    this->nWords = inWords;

    this->words = new char* [this->nWords];
    for (w=istart; w<(istart+this->nWords); w++) {
        this->words[k] = new char [1+strlen(iwords[w])];
        this->words[k] = strcpy(this->words[k], iwords[w]);
        k++;
    }
}

void XWORD::del_words() {
    int w = 0;
    for (w=0; w<(this->nWords); w++) {
        delete[] this->words[w];
    }
    delete[] this->words;
}

void XWORD::print_words() {
    int w = 0;
    for (w=0; w<(this->nWords); w++) {
        printf("\n%s",this->words[w]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

However, when I call the following function, I get the Dr. memory errors shown below (`init_arr` and `del_arr` alone don't give errors either):

```
void XWORD::add_word_to_arr(int iw, int iy, int ix) {
    int k = 0;
    int y = iy;
    int x = ix;

    for (k=0; k<(int)strlen(this->words[iw]); k++) {
        this->arr[y][x] = this->words[iw][k];
        if (this->vdir) {
            y++;
        } else {
            x++;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    XWORD x;
    x.set_words(1, argc-1, argv);
    x.init_arr(10,10);

    x.add_word_to_arr(0, x.len/2, x.wid/2); // WITHOUT THIS, NO ERRORS
    x.print_words();

    x.del_words();
    x.del_arr();
}
```

Dr. Memory Errors:

```
c:\MinGW\WORKSPACE\cpp\xword>make runmem
drmemory -brief -batch bin/test.exe
~~Dr.M~~ Dr. Memory version 1.8.0
~~Dr.M~~ Running "bin/test.exe"
~~Dr.M~~
~~Dr.M~~ Error #1: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS beyond heap bounds: reading 4 byte(s)
~~Dr.M~~ # 0 XWORD::add_word_to_arr               [../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/crt1.c:301]
~~Dr.M~~ # 1 main                                 [../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/crt1.c:302]
~~Dr.M~~ Note: refers to 0 byte(s) beyond last valid byte in prior malloc
~~Dr.M~~
~~Dr.M~~ Error #2: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS: reading 1 byte(s)
~~Dr.M~~ # 0 replace_strlen                       [d:\drmemory_package\drmemory\replace.c:375]
~~Dr.M~~ # 1 XWORD::add_word_to_arr               [../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/crt1.c:301]
~~Dr.M~~ # 2 main                                 [../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/crt1.c:302]
~~Dr.M~~
~~Dr.M~~ Error #3: LEAK 0 bytes
~~Dr.M~~ # 0 replace_operator_new_array               [d:\drmemory_package\common\alloc_replace.c:2638]
~~Dr.M~~ # 1 XWORD::set_words                         [../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/crt1.c:301]
~~Dr.M~~ # 2 main                                     [../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/crt1.c:302]
~~Dr.M~~
~~Dr.M~~ Error #4: LEAK 40 direct bytes + 110 indirect bytes
~~Dr.M~~ # 0 replace_operator_new_array               [d:\drmemory_package\common\alloc_replace.c:2638]
~~Dr.M~~ # 1 XWORD::init_arr                          [../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/crt1.c:301]
~~Dr.M~~ # 2 main                                     [../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/crt1.c:302]
~~Dr.M~~
~~Dr.M~~ ERRORS FOUND:
~~Dr.M~~       2 unique,     2 total unaddressable access(es)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total uninitialized access(es)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total invalid heap argument(s)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total GDI usage error(s)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total handle leak(s)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
~~Dr.M~~       2 unique,     2 total,    150 byte(s) of leak(s)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
~~Dr.M~~ Details: C:\Users\jesse\AppData\Roaming\Dr. Memory\DrMemory-test.exe.4512.000\results.txt
~~Dr.M~~ WARNING: application exited with abnormal code 0xc0000005
make: *** [runmem] Error 5
```

Also, when I print the "%s" of `this->words[0]` within the `add_word_to_arr` function, it is `null`.  Yet it can be printed from `print_words();`.

The exe call is:

```
bin\test.exe a123 b123
```

The `init_arr()` is:

```
void XWORD::init_arr(int ilen, int iwid) {
    int y = 0;
    int x = 0;
    this->len = ilen;
    this->wid = iwid;

    this->arr = new char* [this->len];
    for (y=0; y<(this->len); y++) {
        this->arr[y] = new char [1+this->wid];
        for (x=0; x<(this->wid); x++) {
            this->arr[y][x] = BLANK;
        }
        this->arr[y][x] = (char) NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you use a `std::vector<std::string>` and leave manual memory management alone.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to do that initially, but I got confused about 2d vector notation

Comment: You don't need a 2d vector.  The `std::string` will take the place of a `char*` and wrapping it in a `std::vector` gets rid of having an array of `char*`.

Comment: Show `init_arr()`. You're probably failing to initialize `arr` correctly. How are `len` and `wid` initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Ok `init_arr(10,10)` initializes an array of 10 char arrays of size 11 (10 characters +  1 terminating null).

Then, you call `add_word_to_arr(0, 5, 5)` so you copy first word (first parameter of command line) into the array starting at position 5,5. So if that word is at least 7 characters with vdir == 0 or 6 with vdir != 0 you write past the reserved array. I could successfully run with params "foo" and "bar", but not with "feefoobar".

You should compute the length of the longest word and use it in the call to `int_arr`

Anyway, it looks that you test `vdir` value without initializing it anywhere. This causes undefined behaviour since you cannot know which branch (horizontal or vertical) will be followed, and you really should rewrite `add_word_to_arr` this way:

```
void XWORD::add_word_to_arr(int iw, int iy, int ix) {
    int k = 0;
    int y = iy;
    int x = ix;

    for (k=0; k<(int)strlen(this->words[iw]); k++) {
        this->arr[y][x] = this->words[iw][k];
        if (this->vdir) {
            if (++y >= this.len) return; // refuse to write past allocated mem
        } else {
            if (++x > this.wid) return; // refuse to write past allocated mem
        }
    }
}
```

I executed it under debugger *after forcing vdir value* once to 0 and once to 1 and it never accessed past allocated memory. But I had to imagine some code since you did not gave a [Minimal Compilable Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I wish it were that easy...! Above I showed the exe from the makefile: `bin\test.exe a123 b123` - so the longest word is only `4+null = 5`. In fact the program runs without error when not using Dr. Memory.  However, when I run under Dr.M, the error arises.  I suspect it is something to do with public-private members, maybe even an error in Dr.M...?

Comment: @JesseKnight I could not reproduce after eliminating the remaining undefined behaviour cause. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was running my Dr. Memory tool from my `makefile` and forgot to include `$(ARGS)` in my `make runmem` target:

```
FLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11 -pedantic
LIBS = -Iinclude
SRC = src/xword.cpp
TGT = bin/test.exe
ARGS = human prothean vorcha krogan asari salarian turian batarian quarian

all:
    g++ $(SRC) -o $(TGT) $(FLAGS) $(LIBS)

run:
    $(TGT) $(ARGS)

runmem:
    drmemory -batch $(TGT) **$(ARGS)** # was missing
```

This is why `argv` was empty during the Dr.Memory-encapsulated executions, and why the code would only crash during these.

After adding `$(ARGS)` to the `makefile` here, nothing crashed and no errors/leaks were reported.

Sorry for the goose chase, and thanks for the help -- *please let me know if this is the sort of redundant post which should be removed.*